# how to pass variable from one function to another in the same page in php?

Tags: php, class, function, variables

Ok now i have another problem i want to send one or more variable from one function to another like this:

```
class test{

    var $text2;

    function text1($text1){ // This will catch "This is text" from $text variable.

        $text1 = $this -> text2; // Giving $text1 value to $text2 

        return $this -> text2; // Now here is the trouble i think, i want to send the variable to the next function that is text2(). How do i do that?

    }
    function text2($text2){ // Here is the place that says undefined variable i want the variable $text2 from function text1() to be called here.

        echo $text2; // Now the variable $text2 should echo "This is text".

    }
}

$test = new test();

$text1 = "This is text"; // Assigning value to the variable.

$test -> text1($text1); // Passing the variable as parameter in the function text1().

echo $test -> text2($text2); // Trying to display the value of $text2 that is "This is text".
```

Comment: Is this some sort of variable/function names puzzle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@authors of most other answers: why do you just take bad code and re-use it instead of pointing out the obvious bad practice?

---

You have troubles with your code mainly because it's extremely hard to read! Your functions and variables have the same names which is **bad** and they are **bad** variable and function names in general!

- Function names should have an 'action word' in them, a verb that shows what they do
- Variable names should not contain numbers
- Variable names should describe a container
- Data types make for bad variable names ($string, $text, $int)

Here is an example of how your class could look like, I named in 'TextPuzzler' because of @Matteo Riva 's comment.

```
class TextPuzzler
{
    protected $myText;

    public function setMyText($text)
    {
        $this->myText = $text;
    }

    public function getMyText()
    {
        return $this->myText;
    }

    public function printMyText()
    {
        echo $this->myText;
    }
}

$puzzler = new TextPuzzler();

$text = "This is a random text";

//this is how you set your text
$puzzler->setMyText($text);

//this is how you echo it via a special echo function, not really needed ...
$puzzler->printMyText();

//... because you can also use the getter and echo it like this
echo $puzzler->getMyText();
```

Comment: That's the very habit of stackoverflow. I'd dare to say - the only way SO works. You can't help it. I asked this question on meta several times. Nobody cares.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel : I'm not active on meta but I care that's why I write such comments. If you care, cap your votes :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel In the long run, bad answers get downvoted and good answers get upvoted. I've seen it with many old questions, it sometimes just happens too slowly. Especially since the influx of nOObs.

Comment: Dunno what SO you're talking about but I see no bad answer downvoted on the long run. May be it's PHP only though. Even downvoted ones gets "sympathy upvotes", because being "nice" is way more important than being helpful.

Comment: Yeah, the "sympathy upvotes" get on my nerves too... I see the problem you're addressing... still much better than a forum :)

Comment: Sweet thanks.. :D and i am really much more thankful to you for you guidance regarding proper way of working around with the codes i will surly keep that in mind.

Comment: @Keshav Nair: Do you know how to accept answers? If not, here is how it's done: Choose the answer you want to accept and click on the big 'tick' symbol under the up/down-voting part. All right?

Comment: @Keshav Nair: You don't need any reputation to accept answers!!! It's not voting!

Answer (score 1):

it's not functions but class methods. You don't have to pass anything inside of class, yoy just have to set up class variables

Answer (score 0):

The issue as Markus states is that there is a clash between the variable name and the function name. Also, the assignment was backwards in function text1, php, not smalltalk.

Answer (score -1):

**TRY THIS**

> class test{
>
> var $text2;
>
> function text1($text1){ // This will
>   catch "This is text" from $text
>   variable.
>
> ```
> $text2 = $text1;  // Giving $text1 value to $text2 
>
> $this->text2($text2);
> ```
>
> }
>
> function text2($text2){
>
> ```
> echo $text2; // Now the variable $text2 should echo "This is text".
> ```
>
> }
>
> }
>
> $test = new test();
>
> $text1 = "This is text"; // Assigning
>   value to the variable.
>
> $test -> text1($text1); // Passing the
>   variable as parameter in the function
>   text1().
>
> $test -> text2($text2); // Trying to
>   display the value of $text2 that is
>   "This is text".

Answer (score -1):

I think that you simply have an assignment error.

Try the following in the text1 function

```
function text1($text1){ // This will catch "This is text" from $text variable.

        $this->text2 = $text1; //CHANGE HERE

        return $this->text2; 

}

function text2(){ //CHANGE HERE
        echo $this->text2;
}
```

Assignment happens from right to left.

left = right;

The left side will get the value of the right side.

Answer (score -1):

When you are creating text1 function i think the code should be like this

```
var $text2;
```

function text1($text1){ // This will catch "This is text" from $text variable.

```
text2 = $text1; // Giving $text1 value to $text2 

return text2; // Now here is the trouble i think, i want to send the variable to the next function that is text2(). How do i do that?
```

}

```
function text2($text2){ // Here is the place that says undefined variable i want the variable $text2 from function text1() to be called here.

    echo $text2; // Now the variable $text2 should echo "This is text".

}
```

and one more thing $text2 should be global var

Comment: No, it shouldn't be a global var!